# Julia - Is there a way to avoid using a loop without using too much memory

Tags: performance, julia, allocation

Consider the following example:

```
module structs
mutable struct testStruct
    x::Array{Int64,2}
end
end

function innerFunc(s::structs.testStruct)
    s.x[1:2] .= s.x[3:4]
end

function structTest!(s::structs.testStruct, n)
    for i = 1:n
        innerFunc(s)
    end
    println(s.x)
end
```

The memory allocations, as I increase `n`, increase as well. I think that's because in each iteration, I'm creating an allocation for `s.x[3:4]`. I can avoid this by using a loop:

```
function innerFunc(s::structs.testStruct)
    for i = 1:2
        s.x[i] .= s.x[i+2]
    end
end

function structTest!(s::structs.testStruct, n)
    for i = 1:n
        innerFunc(s)
    end
    println(s.x)
end
```

However, I don't like loops because the syntax is burdensome. Is there a way to avoid it? In each iteration, I want to modify the first and second elements of `s.x` without increasing memory allocations as I increase `n` since I'm not creating anything new.

**UPDATE: In response to DNF, I tried to use `@view`:**

```
module structs
mutable struct testStruct
    x::Array{Int64,2}
end
end

function innerfunc!(s::structs.testStruct)
    s.x[1:2] .= view(s.x, 3:4)
end

function structTest!(s::structs.testStruct, n)
    for i = 1:n
        innerfunc!(s)
    end
    println(s.x)
end
```

This is what I got:

```
@time structTest!(structs.testStruct([1 2 3 4]),33)
0.000112 seconds (202 allocations: 7.938 KiB)

@time structTest!(structs.testStruct([1 2 3 4]),330)
0.000126 seconds (1.69 k allocations: 68.266 KiB)
```

I want the allocations to stay invariant to `n`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think loops are to be avoided? It's the straight-forward solution, why do you think it's burdensome?

Comment: I don't like the syntax. Using vectorized operations (or vectorization-like operations) makes the code look more intuitive.

Comment: Views currently allocate a little bit, but that's one of the optimization issues which is set to be addressed in a 1.x. In general, I wouldn't worry about it because it's small and sooner rather than later it will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DNF noted, using views should have solved the problem, but because views are not immutable, then there is a small memory cost, which in usual applications is immaterial.

So essentially, you have to use a `for` loop. To make it look a bit more vectorized, Dahua Lin's Devectorized.jl package comes to the rescue:

```
# Pkg.add("Devectorized.jl")
using Devectorized

function innerfunc!(s::structs.testStruct)
    @devec s.x[1:2] = s.x[3:4]
end
```

and you are good to go:

```
julia> @time structTest!(structs.testStruct([1 2 3 4]),3300)
  0.000299 seconds (40 allocations: 1.641 KiB)

julia> @time structTest!(structs.testStruct([1 2 3 4]),330000)
  0.001209 seconds (40 allocations: 1.641 KiB)
```

Comment: What's the "for[ce]"? Is `@devec` better than `@view`?

Comment: The "force" is a lamely formatted attempt at a StarWars movie reference. `@devec` is different than `@views`. Views are real Julia structures which can be used and improved through multiple dispatch. `@devec` is more syntactic sugar which transforms vector-like expressions into `for` loops, and thus is more limited.

Comment: Edited out the StarWars reference ("use the **for**ce"). Thought StarWars was already embedded in everyone's DNA, but in case StackOverflow and Julia last longer in meme-memory, it will be better not to confuse future readers.

Comment: Haha I did get the reference at first but I did know that you were referring to the for loop.

Comment: Another question: when I use `BenchmarkTools`, I get the number of allocations and memory used (in MiB): `419.156 ms (72920 allocations: 272.37 MiB)`. I tested two functions, but one has more memory used (measured in MiB) than the other while it uses fewer allocations. Is that possible?

Comment: It definitely could happen. Performance-wise I think the number of allocations is more critical, unless there is orders of magnitude difference in amount. Without details it is hard to know what is happening.

Comment: I'd probably use DNF's solution with a view - the allocations associated with forming a view are so small that they really shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `view`:

```
function innerfunc!(s::structs.testStruct)
    s.x[1:2] .= view(s.x, 3:4)
end
```

or

```
function innerfunc!(s::structs.testStruct)
    @views s.x[1:2] .= s.x[3:4]
end
```

Oh, and put a `!` in the function name, since it mutates the input.

**Edit:** Apparently, I was wrong. Views *do* allocate a little bit. But the way you do the benchmarks will give you very wrong answers, in particular the memory estimates are way off when you benchmark in the global scope. Some tips:

1. Use BenchmarkTools.jl to do the benchmarks.
2. You don't need a mutable struct. You can mutate an array inside an immutable struct.
3. Quibbling, but use `x::Array{Int, 1}` or `x::Vector{Int}` instead of `Array{Int, 2}`.
4. Don't put a `print` statement inside the function unless you really need it!

i.e.

```
struct TestStruct
    x::Vector{Int64}
end

function innerfunc!(s::TestStruct)
    s.x[1:2] .= view(s.x, 3:4)
end

function structtest!(s::TestStruct, n)
    for i = 1:n
        innerfunc!(s)
    end
    return s
end

julia> s = TestStruct([1, 2, 3, 4])
TestStruct([1, 2, 3, 4])

julia> @btime structtest!($s, 33)
  575.108 ns (33 allocations: 1.55 KiB)
TestStruct([3, 4, 3, 4])
```

Comment: I tried, but memory allocations are not invariant to `n`.

Comment: There should be zero allocations.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a Minimal Working Example. The code you pasted cannot actually be run.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you need `$` before `s` in your last line?

Comment: It _interpolates_ the variable into the expression. If `s` a global non-constant variable, the jit compiler has problems optimizing the compiled code. The `$s` splices in the value in the expression and puts it in the benchmark scope. You don't have to do it, the benchmark will still run, but will often give too slow results.